Getting error: a function whose declared type is neither 'undefined', 'void', nor 'any' must return a value
I have a function type that can return void or Promise<void:
export type CommandHandler = (values: CommandValues) => void | Promise<void>;

I'm trying to use it on a void function:
export const handler = (values: CommandValues): CommandHandler => {
  console.log(`hello ${values.name}`);
};

But its crying about the CommandHandler:

A function whose declared type is neither 'undefined', 'void', nor 'any' must return a value.

I don't understand. I've specified that the function can be void in the type. Why is it complaining about this?
I'm expecting it to not have an error because of the way I typed the function.

"I have a function type that can return void or Promise<void" this is a serious design smell. Don't make your functions optionally asynchronous: Callbacks, synchronous and asynchronous | Designing APIs for Asynchrony | Intentionally unleashing Zalgo with synchronous promises

Also, const handler = (values: CommandValues): CommandHandler => ... doesn't make sense here. Did you mean to use const handler: CommandHandler = (values: CommandValues) =>  ...?

(values: CommandValues): CommandHandler => is a function that returns a CommandHandler. It's not a CommandHandler itself. This feels like just a typo or something to me. So (x: string): number => x.length is correct, but (x: string): (x: string) => number => x.length is not.

I don't agree with not using => void | Promise<void>. There are often situations where you don't use the return of the callback, nor await it, and reasonably do not care whether the function is synchronous or asynchronous.

@RobertSandiford that means you just want void.

Weird. I know I've had times were a => void type would not accept an async function, but I cannot reproduce it now. I wonder if I was doing something wrong.

@VLAZ no, because the function may utilize data from sync or async sources. This is for a framework, so think about a CLI function that may or may not use the database.

@RobertSandiford signature which returns void accepts any other return type. The compiler merely doesn't allow you to use the value you get from calling the function: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void

Yes I know. But in some instances the rules are more restrictive - such as return type annotation directly on a function. I recall that when you have a function with a void return type, then make it async, you have to update it to be Promise. Maybe in other places I was doing something unnecessary, so I'll check that in future. Thanks.

: CommandHandler in your code below specifies the return type. TS is expecting the function to return a function based on this typing.
export const handler = (values: CommandValues): CommandHandler => {
  console.log(`hello ${values.name}`);
};

What you probably want is the below, in order to provide a type constraint to the whole function.
export const handler: CommandHandler = (values: CommandValues) => {
  console.log(`hello ${values.name}`);
};

